# Camel - Best practice to start an asynchronous route from another (in request only)

Tags: asynchronous, apache-camel, spring-dsl

In a Camel route I have to start (in async mode and request only) another route countinuing the processing in the main route.

For example: I receive a request, I start in async mode another ruote to write the request on file system (and I'm not interested to know if this operation fails or not), and at the same time I've to process the request in the main route.

What is the best practice to do this? Threads DSL? I'm using Spring DSL.

Comment: How about `wireTap`? http://camel.apache.org/wire-tap.html

Comment: It seems to be what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Yeah wire tap, or you can use the controlbus component and set it to async=true: http://camel.apache.org/controlbus.html